# How to filter an Observable that is an array by a function that returns an Observable of boolean

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs, reactive-programming

Say I have an observable called `selectedUsers$` that returns an Observable that is an array in the following format.

```
[
 {
   'userId': 'someId',
   'other': 'properties',
   'that': 'dont',
   'matter': '.',
 },
 {
   'userId': 'anotherId',
   'other': 'properties',
   'that': 'dont',
   'matter': '.',
 },
 {
   'userId': 'yetAnotherId',
   'other': 'properties',
   'that': 'dont',
   'matter': '.',
 },
];
```

I want to filter this array based on if the user is an administrator or not for a module and only collect the ones that are not administrators. To get if the user is an administrator for a module, a call has to be made to another function that takes the `moduleName` and `userId` value and returns true or false as an Observable.

The signature for the function is

```
isUserAdministratorForModule$(moduleName: string, userId: string): Observable<boolean>
```

The function I want to create is

```
getNonAdministratorUsersForModule$(moduleName: string): Observable<IUser[]> {
   return this.selectedUsers$.map(selectedUsers => selectedUsers.map(user => 
          user.id)
         .filter(userId => !this.userService.isUserAdministratorForModule$(moduleName, userId))
}
```

That's what I have come up with. It is wrong but I have written it so you get a better idea. The problem is the filter is an array method and the function inside of it returns an Observable of boolean.

Any ideas on how to filter an Observable that returns an array and the passed in function in the filter returns an Observable of true or false based on a value on an object in the array?

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Looks like you're using RxJS 5.0 in your snippets, but here's a possible solution with RxJS 6.0.

You should be able to retrofit this.

Aspects to point out:

- `switchMap()` accepts the most recent collection of users returned
- Having to invoke `isUserAdministratorForModule` for each user means you end up with `Observable<boolean>[]`
- Using `of(user)` with `forkJoin()` associates each user with their `isUserAdministratorForModule` result
- The `merge()` then collects each user-result value observable back into a single stream
- Finally, the combination of `filter()` and `map()` weeds out the users of interest

```js
const { forkJoin, merge, of } = rxjs;
const { filter, map, switchMap } = rxjs.operators;

const selectedUsers = [
  {
    'userId': 'someId',
    'other': 'properties',
    'that': 'dont',
    'matter': '.',
  },
  {
    'userId': 'anotherId',
    'other': 'properties',
    'that': 'dont',
    'matter': '.',
  },
  {
    'userId': 'yetAnotherId',
    'other': 'properties',
    'that': 'dont',
    'matter': '.',
  },
];

function isUserAdministratorForModule(moduleName, userId) {
  return of(userId === 'someId');
}

function getNonAdministratorUsersForModule(moduleName) {
  return of(selectedUsers).pipe(
    switchMap(users =>
      merge(...users.map(user =>
        forkJoin(
          of(user),
          isUserAdministratorForModule(moduleName, user.userId))
        ),
      ),
    ),
    filter(([user, isAdmin]) => !isAdmin),
    map(([user, isAdmin]) => user),
  );
}

getNonAdministratorUsersForModule().subscribe(console.log);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/6.4.0/rxjs.umd.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Hey Miqh, this is such a nice solution. I was wondering, if you could return an array of users instead of multiple emits of individual users of the observable? If you could maybe bundle them together to an array of users?

Comment: @WimdenHerder, you absolutely can. One way is to start by changing `merge(...users.map( ... ))`, to `forkJoin(users.map( ... ))`. The outer `forkJoin` ensures that all inner `forkJoin` operations are resolved and the `switchMap` will only emit a single array of tuples (i.e. users paired with their resolved administrator statuses). Following this, you'd change the subsequent `filter` and `map` operators to be compatible with an array of tuples, rather than just tuples.